# How to control Column Type in DataGridView that is bound to a CustomObject?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a C# WinForms app that is DataBound at runtime (through Form_Load) to a custom Object.
In the design view of the DataGridView I have no columns set up.
When the Form loads the the columns are automatically created based on the data in the Custom object that it is DataBound to.
My question is how can I control the the Columns that are automatically created.
For example if I want one of the columns to be a DataGridViewLinkColumn instead of the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn that is automatically created?

Comment: Not to be missed [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/column-types-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default columns are based on the data-type. <s>I haven't checked, but for a link you could *try* exposing the data as `Uri`, but that might be hopeful.</s> Really, if you want a specific type of column - add the columns through code and set [`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to `false`.

As Andrew implies; normally something *like* reflection is used to generate the columns, and you'll get a column for every (browsable + public + readable) property. There is a layer of abstraction on top of this if you need, but this won't help with adding a hyperlink column.

Comment: +1 You may want to mention that reflection is used to auto-generate the columns.

Comment: @Andrew - strictly speaking, it isn't ;-p

Comment: @Marc - Whoops, I definitely thought it was!

Comment: @Andrew - it is `System.ComponentModel`, which could mean `ITypedList`, could mean `ICustomTypeDescriptor` / `TypeDescriptionProvider`, or could be reflection (the default provider). But it can be customized in lots of fun ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-create your columns in the designer. If the name of the column matches the name of the property the column will end up bound to, the databinding will take care of the DGV population for you as before.